# Test Scenario for cookies in selenium webdriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, testng, testcase

I want to work with cookies in my project, I don't know what will be the Test Scenario and Test Cases for it.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

**You can try following scenarios:**

1. **Disabling cookies:** Disable all cookies and attempt to use the site's major functions
2. **Corrupting cookies:** Manually edit the cookie in notepad and change the parameters with some random values
3. **Cookies encryption:** Sensitive information like passwords and usernames should be encrypted before it is sent to our computer
4. **Cookie testing with multiple browser:** Check your website page is writing 
   the cookies properly on different browser as expected
5. **Checking the deletion from your web application page:**
6. **Selectively rejecting cookies:** Delete all the cookies for the websites and see how the website reacts to it
7. **Access to cookies:** Cookies written by one website should not be accessible by others
8. **No overuse of cookies:** If the application under test is a public website, there should not be overuse of cookies
9. **Testing with different setting:** Testing should be done properly to check that website is working well with different cookie setting
10. **Categorize cookies separately:** Cookies should not be kept in the same category of the viruses, spam or spyware

    *- Source guru99*